# Find missing int values from over two or more different dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

For example, I have two arrays:

```
int array_1[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int array_2[9] = {0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 2, 9, 8, 5};
```

How do i find the missing value from array_2 that is present in array_1?

EDIT: Here is my SC. It's just missing the output option wherein I have

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    array<int, 9> k;
    array<int, 10> b = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    cin >> n;

    for (int a = 0; a < n; a ++){ 
     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        cin >> k[i];
         }

      }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what didn't work? Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If there are multiple missing values then learn sorting and then doing binary search.

Comment: Start by reading about `std::set_difference`.

Comment: @Marc I was trying to use *find_if and find_if_not* but I kept getting errors whenever I use them.

Comment: @user6910411 I am not finding a set difference. It's about subtracting sets. I am more into finding the difference of values in each set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard algorithms i.e. :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int array_1[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int array_2[9] = {0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 2, 9, 8, 5};
    int* missingValPtr = std::find_if(std::begin(array_1), std::end(array_1), [&](int arr1Val){
        return std::none_of(std::begin(array_2), std::end(array_2), [&](int arr2Val) {
            return arr1Val == arr2Val;
        }); 
    });
    if(missingValPtr != std::end(array_1)) {
        std::cout << "The missing vlue is: " << *missingValPtr;
    }
}
```